How to I call async tauri commands from leptos UI that return some value?
The documentation and example code showcase the usage when the command does not return a value. They rely on leptos::spawn_local to call the invoke function of tauri.
In my case, I want to return a boolean. However, spawn_local does not return any value. Nor does any other spawn_* function do.
